# Download asset from private repo in java with kohsuke github api

Tags: java, github

I am trying to download assets from a private repository.
I use the kohsuke api, it allows me to see all releases and i can download assets from public repos, but in private repos i still can see all the releases but not download them.

Getting the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://github.com/*username*/*repo*/releases/download/*tag*/asset.jar
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1909)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1117)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1460)
```

The token has all the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The API route for assets is in [`GHAsset.java`](https://github.com/hub4j/github-api/blob/495a46e2d87c26add983cc0bfd803ad5466f3678/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHAsset.java#L152) and might not be complete for private repository download:

```
 return "/repos/" + owner.getOwnerName() + "/" + owner.getName() + "/releases/assets/" + getId();
```

It is a code from 7 years ago ([commit 178c9f](https://github.com/hub4j/github-api/commit/178c9ff4d0f46c40db2bc6e4c3910ae0dd0d29d0))

And it might be missing the `Accept: application/octet-stream` header [mentioned here](https://github.com/miya0001/gh-auto-updater/issues/7#issuecomment-281357701) (in a separate project)

Comment: Thanks, but how could i get the correct link? I am using getBrowserDownloadUrl() and the URL isn´t  
`/repos/" + owner.getOwnerName() + "/" + owner.getName() + "/releases/assets/`
So i have to use another URL And Accept: application/octet-stream?

Comment: @Slendy Not sure about the exact URL, but that is worth testing around, starting with at least adding the missing header.